# QThread stuck in second run

Tags: c++, qt, embedded-linux, qthread

I have a QThread on my embedded device. every time I run the application my thread stuck after second run. I try to kill my thread after first run. Still device stuck after second run. I couldn't run my thread correctly.

**Here is my code;**

```
void ThreadCurrency::run()
{
    QMutex mutex;
    mutex.lock();
    if(this->CurrencyStop == true)
    {
         mutex.unlock();
        return;
    }

    QByteArray strdata;

    // Create QProcess object
    processCurrency = new QProcess();
    processCurrency->start("curl --insecure -v --cacert /data/ca/cert.pem https://secure.*******************/fx.jsp");

    if (processCurrency->waitForStarted(-1))
    {
        while(processCurrency->waitForReadyRead(-1))
        {
            strdata += processCurrency->readAllStandardOutput();
        }

        QMessageBox msgBox1;
        msgBox1.setWindowTitle("eCode Read");
        msgBox1.setText(strdata);
        msgBox1.exec();
    }
    else
    {
        while(processCurrency->waitForReadyRead(-1))
        {
            strdata += processCurrency->readAllStandardError();
        }

        QMessageBox msgBox1;
        msgBox1.setWindowTitle("eCode Error");
        msgBox1.setText(strdata);
        msgBox1.exec();

    }

    mutex.unlock();
    sleep(1);
    //*****************************************************************
    emit CurrencyChanged(aGBP, aEUR, aUSD, sGBP, sEUR, sUSD);
}
```

** The Output shows in a json format:**

```
{
 "date": "20171107", "currency": {
    "dolar": {
        "buy": "3,8200",
        "sale": "3,9050",
        "e_sale": "3,8200"
    },

  }
}
```

---

Thank you for suggestion. The QMutexLocker can’t work in my embedded device. QMutex and the QThread is the closes I can get in my device. 
My problem is the below line: emit CurrencyChanged(aGBP, aEUR, aUSD, sGBP, sEUR, sUSD);  The line runs but It doesn’t fire onCurrencyChanged SLOT. Anything in onCurrencyChanged doesn’t run. My main thread code is:

```
currencyThread = new ThreadCurrency (this);
connect(currencyThread,SIGNAL(CurrencyChanged(QString, QString, QString, QString, QString, QString)), this, SLOT(onCurrencyChanged (QString, QString, QString, QString, QString, QString)));
currencyThread->CurrencyStop = false;

currencyTimer = new QTimer(this);
connect(currencyTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()),this, SLOT(showCurrencyStatus()));
currencyTimer->start(30000); 


void MainWindow::onCurrencyChanged(QString aGBP, QString aEUR, QString aUSD, QString sGBP, QString sEUR, QString sUSD)
{
    // SHOW Currency
    ui->lblALIS_STG->setText(aGBP);
    ui->lblALIS_EUR->setText(aEUR);
    ui->lblALIS_USD->setText(aUSD);
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();

}
```

Comment: What is the output ?

Comment: QThreat - now that's a cool class name! Is it a threatening thread?

Comment: @Marco I update my post

Comment: Not directly related: You might want to use `QMutexLocker` that would simplify the use of mutex. See: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutexlocker.html

Comment: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: when I look why you are using threads than this is good example of fools gold: something doesn't work smoothly lets use threads since they are so fancy and I can say I'm so pro.

Comment: I agree with Marek, in this case using a thread looks a bad choiche, QProcess already runs another process and can run asycronously using the finished() signal so you do not have problems of UI blocked.

Comment: I update my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You are not allowed to access Widgets in a thread besides the main thread.
Thus move all `QMessageBox` code to the main thread (e.g. after receiving the `CurrencyChanged` signal).

2) Make sure, that the `CurrencyChanged` signal is connected using a `QueuedConnection`, otherwise, your GUI will be executed inside the secondary worker thread.

3) Do not use `QMutex` directly, use a [`QMutexLocker`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutexlocker.html) instead

4) Why do you need the Mutex anyhow? Locking based on (arbitrary) input thus arbitrary time is close to deadlocking your application.

Comment: You definitely need to call connect(currencyThread,SIGNAL(CurrencyChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(onCurrencyChanged (QString, QString, QString, QString, QString, QString)), Qt::QueuedConnection);

Comment: And do not call QCoreApplication::processEvents();

Comment: Also you emit CurrencyChanged(aGBP, aEUR, aUSD, sGBP, sEUR, sUSD), but your connect has CurrencyChanged(QString). Can we see your signal declaration!?

Comment: Full post updated with working code. Thank you @Jens